# Why were so many Soviet films shot in 1938–39 about a future German invasion?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, interwar

Why were so many Soviet films about an anticipated Nazi German invasion into the USSR shot in 1938–1939, both before the Molotov-Ribbentrop pact and after it?

Before the Molotov-Ribbentrop pact Nazi Germany had no shared border with the USSR, yet the movies show German (and not, say, Polish) invasion.
After the pact, the countries were formally friendly, but still the USSR issued many films about a sudden German invasion.
Could the public of the time interpret such films as an indication of Soviet desire to invade Germany (especially given in all such films the Soviets usually pushed the enemies back and defeated the Germans on German territory)?

Most of such films were destroyed after the war, but here are some examples:

- [Tankers (1939)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Uyo9WOb6nM) - the invading power is clearly Germany, the officers with German names speak about "Versalles humilation" and superiority of Aryan race. They call themselves "Aryan army". They also consult with the "Supreme Leader". The soldiers wear Stahlhelm.
- [If a war is tomorrow (1938)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPAe2gAu1pU) - the officers of the invaders speak German language, speak about superiority of their race, and the helmets and tanks have swastikas (although the design of the helmets is French).
- [Deep raid (1938)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDd6dno2Wi4)
- [Squadron No. 5 (1939)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be2N7C4lmNA) - again, the invading power is Nazi Germany

Comment: Alexander Nevski might also belong on the list (invaders are Germans and some of the helmets look like Wehrmacht helmets).

Comment: @Jan yes. Also Motherland calls (1936) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH2dXEl3Mg4 The invading planes have swastikas on them. Although Finland also had swastika as an emblem of its air force, the final scene where swastika melts conducts more meaning that just random emblem. The enemy supposedly suddenly invaded without declaration of war and in violation of all treaties (the announcement being done during an opera performance). There is also a long list of films destroyed after the war started.

Comment: Considering that other powers supported the white troops (the last invasion attempt in a way), this is indeed an intersting question.

Comment: I don't think i can do a full answer, but Hitler was already known as a warmonger, and especially stated that Slavs weren't aryan and were actually subhumans by their standards.
That would most likely make Russians kind of wary

Comment: I think it's pretty much confirmed that, from at least '33 onward, Stalin assumed a German invasion. Was this belief widespread in the soviet union or at least the party?  much historiography concentrates on Stalin so that may be not trivial to answer, but could be an avenue when answering this question.

Comment: [securitization](https://www.e-ir.info/2018/01/14/securitisation-theory-an-introduction/) comes to mind,  "According to securitisation theory, political issues are constituted as extreme security issues to be dealt with urgently when they have been labelled as ‘dangerous’, ‘menacing’, ‘threatening’, ‘alarming’ and so on by a ‘securitising actor’ who has the social and institutional power to move the issue ‘beyond politics’."

Comment: To create a foreign enemy to unite the people behind the party during times of terror and purges? (Merely postulating).

Comment: Given that Germans invaded Russian territory within living memory of most of those who made these movies and that the German leader of the time was vocally anti-Soviet, it shouldn't be all that surprising.

Comment: "Mein Kampf" dates back to 1925, and states in no uncertain terms that Hitler deemed war inevitable, and since the rise of the Bolsheviks, deemed it inevitable that this war would have to be waged against Soviet Russia. When you have this kind of clear statement by an omnipotent head of state, the only open question is "when?".

Comment: Because Soviet Union was preparing to invade Germany.

Comment: Those years were the time of the Civil War in Spain, in which both Germany and the Soviet Union were involved. From reading pre-war fiction and later memoirs, it seems that the Soviet public was obsessed with the Spanish war, and it was seen as the last rehearsal before the great war with “the German fascists”.  So was not just films, it was everywhere in the air

Comment: @Jan, yes, it does belong, but here is the catch: it was promptly banned (even if 'unofficially') after signing the Pact, and until after start of the war. All these films, even those from 1939, were made _before_ the Pact.